# Converting PDF text to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I read pdf file using python. Now I want to make a dataframe out of it. I cleaned the texts using "replace"

I replaced '\n' with commas and spaces and made the text into readable format

```
obj = obj.replace('\n',',').replace('\n','').replace(',',' ')
line1 = obj.replace('Serial Number', 'Serial Number break').replace('1  2  3  4  5  6 7 8 9 10', '1  2  3  4  5  6 7 8 9 10 break')
line1 = line1.split(' break')
```

I want a dataframe with Serial Number as the header and 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 as the values in columns. I also have text after this which is not in a structured way. I want to know how do i make a data frame.
Serial
Number
1

2

3

4

5

6
7
8
9
10

Answer (score 0):

This should make a DF with "Serial Number 1" to "Serial Number 10" as Column names

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['Serial Number' + str(x) for x in range(1,11)])
```